# Wireless connection on Ubuntu keeps dropping

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking

I have Ubuntu OS on my Samsung Q310 laptop.

Despite having more than 90% signal strength and a high speed Internet connection (Virgin), the total sent and received keeps changing to 0, and the everything will stop working. This happens especially when I am watching movies.

Here is a snapshot of my network activity:

[image: snapshot]

Any ideas what might be wrong and how I could fix it?

Comment: Are you able to connect the laptop wired to the router so it can be isolated to either the wifi or internet connection?

Comment: Does this happen when you are actively using the mouse and keyboard or could this be related to power saving?